# Can we have infinitely many conjugacy classes of stabilizer subgroups?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group acting smoothly on a smooth connected manifold $M$. Say that $p,q\in M$ have the same **orbit type** if their stabilizer subgroups $G_p$ and $G_q$ are conjugate in $G$.

> Can there be infinitely many orbit types?

In other words, if $[G_p]$ denotes the conjugacy class of $G_p$ in $G$, is it possible that the set
$$\{[G_p]:p\in M\}$$
is infinite?

Comment: Is M connected? compact?..

Comment: @TsemoAristide As stated in question, $M$ is connected. I don't assume that $M$ is compact, but if you have an answer in that situation, I would still be interested.

Answer (score 1):

There exits finitely orbit type if $M$ is compact. See p. 15 here

https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math661/LectureNotesLee.pdf